# Adding dll file reference to c# csproj file

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning c# and trying to add a dll file reference in a `.csproj` file because I am using VsCode.
This is the following xml code in my `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="Utilites">
      <HintPath>.\utilities.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I put the utilies.dll file in my `bin\Debug\net8.0` folder since I think the path has to be relative to the build folder. Now, here is my code in my current `Program.cs` file:

```
using utilities;

var numbers = new int[] {1,2,3};
Console.WriteLine(numbers.AsString());
```

I am trying to access a `AsString` extension method in the assembly and still getting a compiler error in VsCode that the namespace can't be found.

Any thoughts to why I am getting the error?

Comment: If "Utilities" is another project (you have the source code for, and you want to compile the two projects together), you might want to make a project reference rather than a dll reference.

Comment: Yes, I have the source code and the project. I am just trying to learn as much as I can about c# and csproj files so I am trying to add the dll file this way.

Comment: `bin\Debug\net8.0` is cleared before building, so the file does not exist there until AFTER compilation. Put your files in the source folder, then they will be copied to output folder. The path should be relative to the project folder.

Comment: Interesting @PoulBak Thanks for the help. I guess it works now. So essentially MSBuild will build everything in the normal project folder and then the IDE will run the executable in the bin\Debug\net8.0 folder?

Comment: That's right. You can of course create a subfolder for your dlls and use the relative path in .csproj file.